# How to convert a file format from tar.gz to tar.bz2 using the windows console?

Tags: windows-7, python, tar, bz2

I have some python packages in `tar.gz` format that I need to convert to `tar.bz2`. Is there a way to do that in the windows console?

thanks!

Comment: [cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) has both `tar` and `bzip2`

Comment: You tagged your question with `python`.  Did you specifically want to know how to do the above in a Python script?

Comment: if you can it would be nice